# correct my sentence

Tags: tenses, present-tense

I want to explain in english what is "flour". I can explain it with next sentences:

*Flour is white powder from which bread is made of.*

*Flour is white powder of which bread is made of.*

Are my sentences correct? Correct me if I have been mistaken.

Comment: Leave off the _of_ in both and you're fine.

Comment: Formal: leave off the **final** 'of' in each sentence. Informal: remove the central prepositions (from, of) but let the final prepositions ('of) remain.

Comment: 'Flour is the white powder from which bread is made.' You need the definite article in there, to be truly colloquial.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would add 'the' before 'white powder' as well as leaving off the 'of'.
More simply, try: "Flour is the white powder used in making bread."